# Comment traduit-on « moving the goalposts » (erreur de logique lors d'un échange) ? / How do you translate « moving the goalposts » (debate fallacy)?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

Comment traduit-on l'expression idiomatique *to move the goalposts* (« To alter the terms of an agreement or an agreed target, or the rules of a negotiation while it is ongoing, especially in an unfair way », [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/move_the_goalposts) : disons *modifier les conditions d'une entente ou les cibles sur lesquelles on s'est entendu, ou le cadre de la négotiation alors qu'elle est en cours, en particulier de manière inéquitable...* ; [davantage](https://web.archive.org/web/20170909091626/http://www.nytimes.com/1990/10/28/magazine/on-language-moving-the-goalposts.html)...) quand on décrit une erreur de logique lors d'un échange. Par exemple :

---

How would your precisely translate the idiom *to move the goalposts* (« To alter the terms of an agreement or an agreed target, or the rules of a negotiation while it is ongoing, especially in an unfair way », [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/move_the_goalposts); [more](https://web.archive.org/web/20170909091626/http://www.nytimes.com/1990/10/28/magazine/on-language-moving-the-goalposts.html)) to describe a logical fallacy in the context of a debate. For instance:

---

> They couldn't provide a single valid argument to support their
> preposterous claim so they kept **moving the goalposts** during the
> protracted and, needless to say, futile discussion.

Comment: Une erreur de logique dans un échange? Je le percevrais plutôt comme de la mauvaise foi qu'une erreur (laquelle pourrait être une simple inadvertence...) Ou je comprends mal?

Comment: @Pasunclue Ça [pourrait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_the_goalposts#Use) l'être ? Je ne maîtrise pas parfaitement l'expression, je lis « Moving the goalposts is an informal fallacy [...] » (Wikipedia). Il pourrait y avoir motivation ou simplement le désir de ne pas perdre ou de gagner à tout prix qui ferait qu'on a recours à cet « outil ». Personne n'est à l'abri de telles erreurs et évidemment si on analysait on pourrait en voir partout mais il faut aussi alors voir du côté des _biais_, comme celui de _confirmation_. C'est une roue sans fin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait une expression exactement équivalente, mais dans la plupart des cas, l'expression idiomatique en français est « **changer les règles du jeu** », souvent sous une forme plus longue « changer les règles du jeu en cours de route » ou « changer les règles du jeu en cours de partie ». C'est une traduction qui revient fréquemment dans la base [Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/moving+the+goalposts.html).

> Ils étaient incapables d'avancer le moindre argument valable pour justifier leur affirmation ridicule, et n'ont fait que de chercher à sans cesse changer les règles du jeu durant la discussion qui en fut alambiquée et, sans surprise, futile.

Je trouve que c'est un cas un peu marginal où « changer les règles du jeu » ne convient pas forcément parce que les règles du jeu ont pu être imposées de l'extérieur. La traduction dépend de si c'est un débat vu sous un angle extérieur (donc les personnes critiquées n'avaient pas le pouvoir de définir les règles) ou si les personnes critiquées étaient à l'origine du débat (donc elles avaient défini les règles au départ). Avec « *chercher à* changer les règles du jeu », je pense que ma traduction marche dans les deux cas. On peut retirer « chercher à » dans le deuxième cas.

Comment: Merci, il me manquait sans doute ce « chercher à », essayer constamment de, et le _en cours de route_. Est-ce que finalement c'est pas plus simple de dire « tout le temps changer de sujet plutôt que de clore la discussion sur une défaite » (non). Est-ce que _passer/sauter constamment du coq à l'âne pour qqc. (prop.)_ en constitue une application ; est-ce une abstraction utile dans le genre de contexte de la question ou uniquement de très très loin comme spectateur en effet ?

Comment: @némésie-t-île Non, “moving the goalposts”, ce n'est pas changer de sujet. C'est changer d'affirmation, mais en général sur le même sujet. Passer du coq à l'âne, c'est changer de sujet brusquement, et il n'y a pas en général de mauvaise fois.

Comment: Oui, parce que si vous change the goalposts, vous changez, ce qui, au fond, sont les régles du jeu.